# How do I remove the window border in Godot?

Tags: godot, window-management

I want to show my Godot engine game in a borderless window, but not fullscreen. I want to just have the game view visible on screen with no title bar or window chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[A quick search for "Godot bordeless window"](https://www.google.com/search?q=godot%20borderless%20window) turns up some useful hits, including this [official documentation about Godot's `OS` class](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_os.html):

> `bool window_borderless` - If `true` removes the window frame.